# Determining the probability of measuring a particular eigenvalue for angular momentum given the angular wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, probability, eigenvalue, quantum-measurements

Suppose I know the  normalised angular wave function of a particle that is defined as $\psi(\theta,\phi)$

How would I use this to determine the probability of measuring a particular observable such as the probability of measuring a particular angular momentum.

Say that $L^2 = 2\hbar^2$ this would correspond to an angular momentum of $l=1$.

But how would I know the probability for measuring this.

I know that $$\int\int_{}\ |\psi(\theta,\phi)|^2 \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$$ would give me the probability of finding a particle in a particular position but am unsure how to change this to determine the probability of measuring $L^2 = 2\hbar^2$ or  an angular momentum of $l=1$.

Comment: Have you learned about spherical harmonics?

Comment: my bad it should be 1

Comment: Also I have studied spherical harmonics before but just seem unable to work this one out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the measurement is ideal, the act of measurement leaves the initial state in an eigenstate of the measured observable compatible with the result. So the probability of measuring a particular eigenvalue is best interpreted as the transition probability from the state prior to the measurement to an eigenstate of that particular eigenvalue (“*an* eigenstate” because the eigenspace could have degeneracy $>1$). For an observable $A$ and an initial state $\vert\psi\rangle$ you get, if $\langle\psi\vert\psi\rangle =1$,
$$P_\psi^A(a_n)=\sum_{r=1}^{d(a_n)}\vert\langle\psi\vert a_n,r\rangle\vert^2$$
where $\vert a_n,1\rangle,\dots,\vert a_n, d(a_n)\rangle$ are the eigenstates of $A$ of eigenvalue $a_n$, with $d(a_n)$ the dimension of the eigenspace.

In the case in question, the operator $A$ would be the angular momentum $L$ with its eigenstates, which for the angular part are the spherical armonics $Y_\ell^m$. So the probability of measuring $\mathbf{L}^2=2\hbar^2$ is the sum of the transition probability from $\psi$ to $Y_1^1$ plus those from $\psi$ to $Y_1^{-1}$ and from $\psi$ to $Y_1^{0}$.